# How to Pass Next Level Alphabetical String using C#?

Tags: c#

I would like to pass if input string is "A" means i need to get next leve as "B". If input value is "B" means "C".

**E.g:**

```
string input1 = "A";
string input2 = "B";

output:
input1 ---> B
input2 ---> C
```

How to do it in programmatically. Please give me a solution to do this.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the problem, it seems like you want the next alphabetical character?

Comment: What if the string contains more than 1 chars, say ABC?

Comment: Yes..I need a nex alphabetical character.

Comment: Each letter is represented by a number, just grab the next number in line.

Comment: String always come 1 char. A to Z. Not more than that.

Comment: So, then use char as parameter type, then cast to int and increment 1. Of course, you have to check if the input is 'Z' before incrementing

Comment: `String result = new String((Char) (input[0] + 1), 1);` you have to deal with `Z`

Answer (score 1):

This is the best as far as i understand the problem:

```
public char NextLevel(char c)
{
    if (c == 'Z')
       return 'A';

    return (char)(c + 1);
}
```

Comment: `return (char) (c + 1);` is enough

Comment: The question requested the input should be string

Comment: As per @dhamo: "String always come 1 char. A to Z. Not more than that." See comments on the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private string NextChar(string character)
    {
        if (character == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(character));
        if (character.Length != 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(character), "You can use only a single letter string");

        return Convert.ToString(NextChar(character[0]));
    }

    private char NextChar(char character)
    {
        return (char)(character + 1);
    }
```

If you need more details you can use this link: https://github.com/jenseralmeida/stackoverflow/blob/q37608162/src/LibraryTests/DraftTests.cs

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you.

```
public string NextAlphaString(string x)
{
    if(x == "z" || x == "Z")
        return x.Replace(x[0],(char)(x[0] - 25));
    else
        return x.Replace(x()[0],(char)(x[0] + 1));
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Any comments?

Comment: No idea why it was downvoted, but you can shorten `x.ToCharArray()[0]` to `x[0]`.

Comment: @Maarten: Thanks. Point taken! :)

Comment: You could shorten the whole method to: `return x.Replace(x[0],(char)(x[0] + ((x == "z" || x == "Z") ? -25 : 1)));`

Comment: No no. I prefer that to `if statement` only. They undergo same complexity and `if` is, in this case, more readable than conditional operators.